# Where does int 32 value come from in Memory viewer, Cheat Engine

Tags: cheat-engine

In the memory viewer, I'm at 333CF2F4, which holds a value of float 500, as cheatviewer tells me. But it also has a value for a integer. How is that value calculated? Is it the hex value of  0000FA43?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like it's little endian, so the integer value 1140457472 is 0x43FA0000.

Those numbers along the bar at the bottom are just the different representations of the data stored at those addresses.

Comment: Right, so 43FA 0000 in a calculator becomes that value. But when I put a decimal '500' in my calculator, it becomes something else..how would I get the float from that hex?

Comment: It's a bit long for a comment, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format shows how to convert to/from floating point format.

Comment: Thank you..I'll probably make a new question for this, plenty of questions on how PHP handles this sortof thing :)